# WxPython window not closing

Tags: python, wxpython

I learnt how to detect window closing using WxPython but I have a problem. When I click 'X' on the top right corner I expect a dialog to appear saying 'Are you sure you want to exit?' And 2 buttons, Yes or no appear. That is fine. But when I click Yes, it is supposed to close but when I click No, it's supposed to not close. No is working fine but when I click yes, the dialog closes and opens again and I cannot close the main application...I had to use Task manager...What am I doing wrong? Please help me! Here is my close function:

```
def OnExit(self, event):
    
    if event.GetEventType() == wx.EVT_CLOSE.typeId:
        
        dial = wx.MessageDialog ( None, 'Are you sure you want to exit?', 'Exclamation',
        wx.YES_NO | wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION )
        
        if dial.ShowModal() == wx.ID_NO:
            
            pass
        
        else:
            self.Close()
```

Please help me! Any replies will be appreciated!!Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are, after all, calling `self.Close()` and therefore creating a new EVT_CLOSE event, to put you in an infinte loop.
`And`, because of the structure of your `if` statement, you can no longer close the program with `File`->`Quit`, using the menu.
I'd suggest something along these lines.

```
    if event.GetEventType() == wx.EVT_CLOSE.typeId:
        
        dial = wx.MessageDialog ( self, 'Are you sure you want to exit?', 'Exclamation',
        wx.YES_NO | wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION )
        
        if dial.ShowModal() == wx.ID_NO:
            return
        
    self.Destroy()
```

Comment: the correct method to close a wx.Frame is wx.Frame.Destroy()

Comment: yes in fact i upvoted  it, the comment was made to support what the code in your answer said